# Не выводится поле для ввода реквизитов карты в 1с битрикс

Tags: битрикс

В корзине есть способ оплаты "сбербанк оплата картой", если выбрать его и оформить заказ то не появляется поле ввода реквизитов карты, просто кидает на страницу "заявка оформлена". Заявка приходит в админку.

стоят плагины:

Покупай со сбербанком (rbs.credit)

Прием платежей через Сбербанк(rbs.payment)

Оплата картой банка - Sberbank (sberbank.ecom)

Интернет-магазин Aspro (aspro.ishop)

Аспро: Маркет - Адаптивный интернет-магазин (aspro.mshop)

это не все, а только те которые как то могут влиять на эквайринг. Может это быть связано с тем что сбер отключили от swift?

Answer (score 0):

Семь бед – один reset!

Может быть обновить модуль Сбербанка?